# ¿Cómo cargar rutas anidadas en Angular?

Tags: html, angular, rutas

Tengo un navbar que me tiene que cargar la rutas secundarias de un panel de administración.

En el navbar tengo lo siguiente:

```
<ul *ngIf="isAdmin" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item mr-2">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="check_messages" [routerLinkActive]="['navbar-active-link']">
          <div class="navbar-icon-container"><i class="fas fa-check fa-lg mr-1"></i></div>{{keys.nav_option_5}}
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mr-2">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="create_admin" [routerLinkActive]="['navbar-active-link']">
          <div class="navbar-icon-container"><i class="fas fa-user-cog fa-lg mr-1"></i></div>{{keys.nav_option_6}}
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mr-2">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="mod_info" [routerLinkActive]="['navbar-active-link']">
          <div class="navbar-icon-container"><i class="fas fa-user fa-lg mr-1"></i></div>{{keys.nav_option_7}}
        </a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

En mi fichero **app-routing.module.ts** tengo lo siguiente relacionado a las rutas:

```
  { path: 'home', component: AdminHomeComponent, children: [
    {path: 'check_messages', component: CheckMessagesComponent},
    {path: 'create_admin', component: CreateAdminComponent},
    {path: 'mod_info', component: ModAdminInfoComponent}
  ]},
```

El navbar está obviamente en la ruta *home*.

El problema está en que cuando le doy a los diferentes enlaces, me manda a una ruta por defecto que tengo porque la ruta no la construye bien. Es decir, si por ejemplo le doy a la ruta de *create_admin*, me debería de mandar a la ruta *"localhost:4200/home/create_admin"*, pero me manda a la ruta *"localhost:4200/create_admin"*.

Cual es el problema?

Comment: `path: 'home/create_admin'` ?

Comment: Esto lo había pensado, pero la ruta la escribes a mano. Lo que estoy buscando es una forma de hacerlo automático, sin escribir el componente padre.

Comment: probaste `routerLink="home/create_admin"` ?

Comment: y si pones la ruta entre dobles comillas y comilla simple ? ej: [routerLink]="'/home/create_admin'"